# Did Mohammed (saw) see Allah (subhana wa taala)?

Tags: prophet-muhammad, allah

Did the Prophet Muhammad (saws) ever see Allah (SWT)?

Comment: Grrrr People simply loves downvoting ! This is a good question.

Comment: Yes, but not with the eyes of face but the eyes of heart, God willing me or someone else will give a more thorough answer with references regarding this issue. [Seeing with heart but still needs clarification, for now note the difference between وجه الله and الله]

Answer (score 7):

No one in this life can see Allah, as He said:

> لاَ تُدْرِكُهُ الأَبْصَارُ وَهُوَ يُدْرِكُ الأَبْصَارَ وَهُوَ
> اللَّطِيفُ الخَبِيرُ
>
> Vision perceives Him not, but He perceives [all] vision; and He is the
> Subtle, the Acquainted.

[Suratul An'aam Ayat 103](http://quran.com/6/103)

The Prophet ﷺ never saw Allah with his eyes, it is narrated that A'ishah (May Allah be please with her) said:

> O Abu 'A'isha (kunya of Masruq), there are three things, and he who
> affirmed even one of them fabricated the greatest lie against Allah. I
> asked that they were. She said: He who presumed that Muhammad (ﷺ) saw
> his Lord (with his ocular vision) fabricated the greatest lie against
> Allah. I was reclining but then sat up and said: Mother of the
> Faithful, wait a bit and do not be in a haste. Has not Allah (Mighty
> and Majestic) said:" And truly he saw him on the clear horizon"
> (Al-Qur'an, Surat at-Takwir, 81:23) and" he saw Him in another
> descent" (Al-Qur'an, Surat Najm 53:13)? She said: I am the first of
> this Ummah who asked the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) about it, and he said:
> Verily he is Gabriel. I have never seen him in his original form in
> which he was created except on those two occasions (to which these
> verses refer); I saw him descending from the heaven and filling (the
> space) from the sky to the earth with the greatness of his bodily
> structure. She said: Have you not heard Allah saying: "Eyes comprehend
> Him not, but He comprehends (all) vision. and He is Subtle, and
> All-Aware" (Al-Qur'an, Surat al-An`am 6:103)? (She, i.e. 'A'isha,
> further said): Have you not heard that, verily, Allah says: "And it is
> not for any human being that Allah should speak to him except by
> revelation or from behind a partition or that He sends a messenger to
> reveal, by His permission, what He wills. Indeed, He is Most High and
> Wise." (Al-Qur'an, Surat ash-Shura, 42:51)

[صحيح مسلم (Muslim)](https://sunnah.com/muslim:177a)

It is also narrated in [Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim:178a) that the Prophet ﷺ said when he was asked if he saw Allah:

> نُورٌ أَنَّى أَرَاهُ
>
> Light; how could I see Him?

Answer (score 4):

Sure No,

Nobody have seen ALLAH, No one of prophets have seen, nobody can.

When ALLAH appears to moussa the mountain is flushed and moussa fainted since no human can be able to hold such thing

ALLAH is everywhere and he is a light no eyes can see but only in heart.

Comment: Hello and welcome [islam.se]. Good answer.